# Function to read fasta files not working after update python

Tags: python, iterator, python-itertools

I got a good code to read fasta files:

```
from itertools import groupby


def is_header(line):
    return line[0] == '>'


def parse_fasta(filename):
    if filename.endswith('.gz'):
        opener = lambda filename: gzip.open(filename, 'rb')
    else:
        opener = lambda filename: open(filename, 'r')
    with opener(filename) as f:
        fasta_iter = (it[1] for it in groupby(f, is_header))
        for name in fasta_iter:
            name = name.__next__()[1:].strip()
            sequences = ''.join(seq.strip() for seq in fasta_iter.__next__())
            yield name, sequences.upper()
```

And it worked fine until I update to Python 3.10.4, then when I try to use it I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/paulosschlogl/Paulo/pauloscchlogl/Genome_kmers/fasta_parser.py", line 21, in parse_fasta
    sequences = ''.join(seq.strip() for seq in fasta_iter.__next__())
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/paulosschlogl/Paulo/pauloscchlogl/Genome_kmers/fasta_split_chr_pls.py", line 112, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/media/paulosschlogl/Paulo/pauloscchlogl/Genome_kmers/fasta_split_chr_pls.py", line 81, in main
    plasmid, chromosome = split_sequences_from_fasta_file(filename)
  File "/media/paulosschlogl/Paulo/pauloscchlogl/Genome_kmers/fasta_parser.py", line 111, in split_sequences_from_fasta_file
    for header, seq in parse_fasta(filename)
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

I run my code in conda (conda 4.13.0) environment, and I try to debug the function but I got stucked.
I don't want to loose this function to try use Biopython.
If you guys have any idea to fixe it I really appreciate.
Thanks
Paulo

Example of fasta file:

```
> seq_name
  AGGTAGGGA
```

The funny stuff is that, when I run the function in python interpret at the command line all worked fine, but when I call the functions from the script using the function imported thats when I got the errors.

```
>>> import gzip
>>> from itertools import groupby

>>> def is_header(line):
...     return line[0] == '>'
... 
>>> for name, seq in parse_fasta("/media/paulosschlogl/Paulo/pauloscchlogl/Genome_kmers/Genomes/Archaea/Asgard/Chr/GCA_008000775.1_ASM800077v1_genomic.fna.gz"):
...     print(name, seq[:50])
... 
CP042905.1 Candidatus Prometheoarchaeum syntrophicum strain MK-D1 chromosome, complete genome TAAATATTATAGCCCGTAATAGCAGAGTCACCAACACTTAAAGGTGCATC
>>> quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you're getting is because you're manually calling the `__next__` method on various iterators in your code. Eventually you do that on an iterator that doesn't have any values left, and you'll get a `StopIteration` exception raised.

In much older versions of Python, that was OK to leave uncaught in a generator function. The `StopIteration` exception would continue to bubble up just like any other exception. For a generator function, raising `StopIteration` is an expected part of its behavior (it happens automatically when the function ends, either with a `return` statement, or by reaching the end of its code). In Python 3.5, this behavior changed, with [PEP 479](https://peps.python.org/pep-0479/) making it an error for a `StopIteration` to go uncaught in a generator.

Now, given the logic of your code, I'm not exactly sure why you're getting empty iterators. If the file is in the format you describe, the `__next__` calls should always have a value to get, and the `StopIteration` that comes when there are no values left will be received by the `for` loop, which will suppress it (and just end the loop). Perhaps some of your files are not correctly formatted, with a header line by itself with no subsequent sequences?

In any case, you can better diagnose the issue if you catch the `StopIteration` and print out some diagnostic information. I'd try:

```
with opener(filename) as f:
    fasta_iter = (it[1] for it in groupby(f, is_header))
    for name in fasta_iter:
        name = name.__next__()[1:].strip()
        try:
            sequences = ''.join(seq.strip() for seq in fasta_iter.__next__())
        except StopIteration as si:
            print(f'no sequence for {name}')
            raise ValueError() from si
        yield name, sequences.upper()
```

If you find that the missing sequence is a normal thing and happens at the end of every one of your files, then you could suppress the error by just putting a `return` statement in the `except` block, or maybe by using `zip` in your `for` loop (`for name_iter, sequences_iter in zip(fasta_iter, fasta_iter):`). I'd hesitate to jump to that as the first solution though, since it will throw away a header if there is an extra one, and silently losing data is generally a bad idea.

Comment: @Bickknght Well, I really don't know what is going on, because as I said I tried to debug to check for each item, but seems that I can't the iterators working anymore...Then it raise the StopIteration. But thank you very much.